# How to use multiple stacks in Microsoft Azure? | NodeJS and Python

Tags: python, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, child-process

I have a nodeJS API which uses child_process to run a python file.

I know heroku has a way to add another buildpack with a script.

Is there a way with Microsoft Azure (web app / app services) to use NodeAPI and Python files in an App service.

PS : Python file is not an API, it is just a script that runs from node.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you hosted a Web App in Azure, you already have all runtime environments by default**.

1. Web App Runtime on Azure Portal:

[image]

2. Python Runtime on Kudu Explorer:

[image]

3. NodeJS and PHP on Kudu Explorer:

[image]

4. Check the other stack versions in Console and if it not sufficient, update them.

[image]

**Note**:

- When creating the webapp, it is recommended to choose windows platform which supports virtual application because when you find that you cannot use the runtime you required, you can try to install runtime extensions for other programs.
- Also, it is possible under Linux but requires command line to operate.